# Three dimensional plot on matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am trying to do a figure similar to the one attached.

I have exactly a (224x1) vector with dates (x-axis), a (10x1) vector with maturities (y-axis) and a (224x10) matrix with the values (z-axis).

I tried surf(X, Y, Z) but I got an error ("data dimensions must agree").

How can I combine this to make a plot like the one attached?

Thanks, V!

Edit: The second plot is the one I am getting using Luis Mendo's suggestion:

[image: 3d plot]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
surf(Y,X,Z)
```

From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) (emphasis added):

> `surf(x,y,Z)` and `surf(x,y,Z,C)`, with two vector arguments replacing
>       the first two matrix arguments, must have `length(x) = n`and
>       `length(y) = m` where `[m,n] = size(Z)`.  In this case, the vertices
>       of the surface patches are the triples (x(j), y(i), Z(i,j)).
>       **Note that `x` corresponds to the columns of `Z` and `y` corresponds to
>       the rows**.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. But the plot seems a bit strange ... I have uploaded the plot I am getting. There are some weird black lines connecting the top and bottom for each date ... Any idea why? Also how can I put the actual dates on the X axis instead of the datenum from matlab?

Comment: Just a quick question, how to put date strings on X axis?

Comment: @volcomp Try something like `set(gca,'xticklabel',{'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3' })`

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

You need to create a meshgrid to be able to plot a surf. X ,Y and Z need to be the same size!

Comment: Ok. So probably surf is not the function that I want to use. If you look to the plot above you can see that X and Y have different lenghts (meaning that on the example above x are several dates and Y has 6 maturities).

Comment: In my exmple X and Y should have different legnths. X should be MxN (here N repetitions of M happens) and Y should be NxM (where M repetition of the orginal size N happen)